# Error of "syntax error near unexpected token `(' " because of the lacking of #!/bin/bash?

Tags: bash, shell

My code is called test.sh, and the content is:

```
echo -e 'Gene_id\tsample_1\tsample_2\tsample_3' > control.countmerged.idx

paste <(awk -F'"' '{print $2}' 1.countmerged.idx) <(awk -F'"' '{print $6}' 1.countmerged.idx) <(awk -F'"' '{print $6}' 2.countmerged.idx) <(awk -F'"' '{print $6}' 3.countmerged.idx) >> control.countmerged.idx
```

Using `sh test.sh` , I got the error:

```
test.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 3: `paste <(awk -F'"' '{print $2}' 1.countmerged.idx) <(awk -F'"' '{print $6}' 1.countmerged.idx) <(awk -F'"' '{print $6}' 2.countmerged.idx) <(awk -F'"' '{print $6}' 3.countmerged.idx) >> control.countmerged.idx'
```

But if I copy-paste the two command lines in the file to execute them manually, it works well.

I also tried another way, which also works:
I add the header `#!/bin/bash` to the file, and change the mode of the file `chmod +x test.sh`, then use `./test.sh`. That also works.

Could somebody help to explain?

Comment: `sh` isn't bash (or when it is, it's bash in [POSIX mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html)).

Comment: `sh` is a POSIX shell and does not support `<( )`, `bash` is a different shell that does support it.  Know which language you are using!